# Facebook developer app not found in mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a facebook app. In the developer options filled lot of details including "Mobile site URL" field. But when I visit from the url in mobile it's not found.This is only for mobile.
Screenshot attached. This app done using php.
[image]

[image]

Please anyone can advice me to fix this.

Comment: how exactly do you access it on mobile? it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It's working when remove the  "Mobile Site URL" from add settings.Not properly resized the layouts. When I add the url it's getting not found error.

Comment: Current bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/